# Python turtle bgpic instantly disappears in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle as t
t.bgpic(picname="image1.gif")
```

and the error is  `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "image1.gif": no such file or directory`

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't the error says it all? The file doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am a 12 years old boy this is my opinion and I think it is true.)

Hi, you have to say

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=700,height=400)
wn.title("image")

wn.addshape(currentDir+"")#where is you picture
#example wn.addshape(currentDir+"\\Resources\\image.gif")

image=turtle.Turtle()
image.speed(0)
image.shape(currentDir+"")# write where is your gif in ""
#so i am useing a mac so i say "downloads\\image.gif"
image.penup()
```